# Find a prove the formula for given sequence by induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Let $a_0 = 1$ and 
$$a_{n} = \frac{a_{n-1}}{2a_{n-1}+1}$$

how to find that formula of the sequence?

Comment: Welcome to stack. You'll get a warmer reception and more helpful commentary if you type your question in MathJax and let us know what you've tried so far.

Comment: If you are just looking for a solution you should try to find a duplicate following the indications given here [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29265/how-to-search-on-this-site) Otherwise let we know what your aim is and show here your effort to solve that.

Comment: Try writing out the first few terms and see if you can find a pattern. Then once you find the pattern use induction to show that it hold for all $n$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for tips on how to properly format your questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we divide through by $a_{n-1}$, to rewrite the seqence as follows;
$$a_{n}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{2a_{n-1}+1}=\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}}$$

Writing out the first few terms gives;

So $\{a_{n}\}=\{1, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{7},...\}$

This looks like the sequence of all odd fractions, $a_{n}=\frac{1}{2n+1}$ to me! Can you prove it by induction from here?

Comment: yes, I can. Thanks)

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help. By the way, don't forget to mark the question solved if you'e figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

you may rewrite your difference equation as
$$
\frac{1}{a_n}=2+\frac {1}{a_{n-1}}
$$
Call $b_n=\frac{1}{a_n}$, then you get the arithmetic progression
$$
b_n=b_{n-1}+2,
$$
with $b_0=1$, $\implies b_n=2n+1\implies a_n=\frac{1}{2n+1}$.